# visual basic form and data grid

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

A rather simple question about linking an Access .mdb data source to a visual basic form. I have database with three tables:

student

loan  #link table

book

The form look like this (it is really a test form not a working live project)

[image]

The first **text box** on the form links to the student id field in the student table.

Below the text box is the **data grid** attached to a query that contains the student id field and fields from other tables.

What I want is to **filter** the data grid so that when I **change** the student ID text box input on the form it changes the **query result** s in the data grid for that student.

I can do it using Access alone but here I am using VB 2010 Express for the GUI.

I think it may have something to do with thi sline of code:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'BisDataSet.student_Query' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.Student_QueryTableAdapter.Fill(Me.BisDataSet.student_Query)
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'BisDataSet.student' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.StudentTableAdapter.Fill(Me.BisDataSet.student)

End Sub
```

as it mentions the data grid is using a filter.

Can anyone tell me **how to filter the data grid using the student  id fierld** on the form?

To make the question clearer:

The result below shows I have selected student 3 but the grid result has not performed the query:
[image]

To summarise how do I bind a dat grid showing a query result to a text box field on a form in VB.net (.mdb file holds the data)

Answer (score 0):

> To group, sort, and filter data in a DataGrid control, you bind the
>   DataGrid to a collection view that supports these functions.

I think [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd833072%28v=vs.95%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) you can find your solution.

Comment: I think there must be a more direct way :your method does not refer to a query critria. MS VB.net has much simpler ways of doing things than this and I am not sure it really answers the question.